# Nothing shows up on the screen after returning jsonify(dictionary)

Tags: python, url, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to build a very simple API I will then fetch data from and my code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import backend as b

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/data/', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    d = {}
    m = b.getMarks(b.login())
    d['Marks'] = str(m)
    return jsonify(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the app and open the web page it just says error 404 (even after typing /api/data/ in the url). Shouldn't my dictionary pop up? Sorry I'm very new to this so thanks in advance.
Also, I know for a fact that my dictionary (d) works, I printed it out.

Comment: 404 error means you gave the wrong URL. So there's a problem with your routing, it has nothing do with what you're returning.

Comment: Thanks! So what should I add to the URL that shows up in the terminal when I run the API?

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake: when running the API, this line

```
@app.route('/api/data/', methods=['GET'])
```

Should be replaced with this one:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
```

So you can just add '/api'to the url.